# IIS UrlRewriter Outbound rules ignored if PreCondition is set

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, urlrewriter

I have a very simple OutBound UrlRewriter rule that rewrites url's it finds in the body of the http response stream:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Scripted" 
          preCondition="IsHtml" 
          patternSyntax="ECMAScript" 
          stopProcessing="false">
      <match filterByTags="None" pattern="http://someurl.com" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="http://anotherurl.com" />
    </rule>

    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="IsHtml" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>

  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem is that as soon as I turn on the `preCondition` no rewriting takes place.

I need to be able to use a pre-condition because the page is an ASP.NET page and uses ASP.NET script resources e.g. `<script src="ScriptResource.axd?d=...." type="text/javascript" />`.

By default script resources are gzip compressed and I want to keep them that way. Without the content type precondition the URL rewriter `RewriteModule` throws a 500.52 error - "*Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip").*"

Using Fiddler I can see that `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` is being sent in the response header but UrlRwriter seems unable to match this.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the Server Variable `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` is not added to the allowed server variables list. Add it there (you can google how to in IIS).

Comment: Another question/answer helps here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723025/customize-http-header-in-iis-url-rewrite-module